# getting group using filter in a regular expression in python

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a dict with a set of keys, and I want to match a regular expression in the keys and get only the group on the matched keys so I do that:

`subject = re.compile(r'(*.)_id')
 dict = {'name': 'Robert', 'customer_id': 2, 'action_id': 5} 
 results = list(filter(subject.match, dict))
 results`

gives me the following

`['customer_id', 'action_id']`

I want to obtain

`['customer', 'action']`

Answer (score 1):

Once you have this list `['customer_id', 'action_id']` you can use `findall` using `^[^_]+` regex to extract the part before `_id`. Try this Python code,

```
import re

subject = re.compile(r'.*_id')
dict = {'name': 'Robert', 'customer_id': 2, 'action_id': 5} 
results = list(filter(subject.match, dict))
results = [''.join(re.findall(r'^[^_]+',s)) for s in results]
print(results)
```

Prints,

```
['customer', 'action']
```

Comment: I need to match some keys that has underscore in the middle, something like first_response_id and I need first_response group thats why I choose `r'.*_id'`

Comment: @HernanAcosta: I could be wrong as I am new to Python but I believe, `filter` function only filters the entries by using the first argument to match the second argument and it doesn't match and extract portion of items in list. For extracting partial text from the list, I feel you will find another operation like I did in my post. May be some Python guru can help here.